# Changing Drupal database

Tags: database

How would you think if a designer extends the database of Drupal for a desired system? (for example adding field to some tables)

Would it be really PRACTICAL?

Comment: I mean that I'm going to do it! I need to hear your recommendation!

Comment: It is not recommended to change the existing database schema of Drupal, unless that is the only option left; which is most of the times is not the case. It might cause problems with the updates.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "practical" in this context? It's not really possible to answer this without knowing exactly what you want to change. Knowing _why_ would also be helpful, so we can convince you to do it the proper way instead

Comment: I would like to add some fields to user table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bottom line: it's your database, you can add as many fields to whatever tables you like.

Drupal won't know anything about them, obviously, and it may cause unforeseen issues further down the line, as you're potentially changing the way the core system works. It's not possible to be any more specific than that without knowing pretty much everything about your application, so you'd need to test until you're happy you haven't broken anything.

The correct way to extend core entities is through the use of [fields](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/field-ui), I'd strongly recommend using those rather than hacking at database tables.

Comment: I tried to find the way with fields and it really worked. thanks